# INSERT and UPDATE in Trigger

Tags: oracle, trigger, select, update, insert

I have created a trigger so I could insert every row in a backup table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER xyz AFTER INSERT
ON table_1
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_2
(Did, Dvalue)
VALUES(:NEW.Did, :NEW.Dvalue);
END ;
```

My question is if I have `AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE` instead of `AFTER INSERT`. Will my trigger try to insert a new row in table_2 every time even if an UPDATE query which is acting on table_1 and throw a `unique constraint` error for that `Did`

**Or like I want, and this is what I am guessing, it will `UPDATE` the same record.**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER xyz AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON table_1
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_2
(Did, Dvalue)
VALUES(:NEW.Did, :NEW.Dvalue);
END ;
```

I get this doubt since I am using `FOR EACH ROW` and `BEGIN INSERT INTO...`

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO table_2` will always insert and never update.  If you need different operation depends on which operation(insert or update) actually fired the trigger,  you need to check it with `IF UPDATING THEN ... END IF;` or (`IF INSERTING THEN ... END IF;` )